# iOS - NSTimer - SIGABRT after invalidate - Edit Now DeAlloc Msg

Tags: iphone, ios4, nstimer, sigabrt

I have my NSTimer embedded in a class that plays image sequences. Basically it loops and changes a UIImageView. Everything goes well if I let the image sequence finish but... on it's own if I try to stop the timer while it is playing I get a sigabrt. Edit: No longer a sigabrt but now a DeAlloc I can't explain.

The "stop" at the end of a frame sequence is the same stop I am calling mid sequence.

So what might cause an NSTimer to break mid function and DeAlloc. More to the point what might I look at to fix it.

Thanks.

I am using some example code from here: http://www.modejong.com/iOS/PNGAnimatorDemo.zip

**Edit:** I'll add what I believe to be the pertinent code here.

// Invoke this method to start the animation

```
- (void) startAnimating
{
    self.animationTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: animationFrameDuration                                         target: self                                      selector: @selector(animationTimerCallback:)                                    userInfo: NULL                                       repeats: TRUE];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: animationTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    animationStep = 0;

    if (avAudioPlayer != nil)
        [avAudioPlayer play];

    // Send notification to object(s) that regestered interest in a start action

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:ImageAnimatorDidStartNotification
     object:self];  
}

- (void) animationTimerCallback: (NSTimer *)timer {
    if (![self isAnimating])
        return;

    NSTimeInterval currentTime;
    NSUInteger frameNow;

    if (avAudioPlayer == nil) {
        self.animationStep += 1;

//      currentTime = animationStep * animationFrameDuration;
        frameNow = animationStep;
    } else {
        currentTime = avAudioPlayer.currentTime;
        frameNow = (NSInteger) (currentTime / animationFrameDuration);
    }

    // Limit the range of frameNow to [0, SIZE-1]
    if (frameNow < 0) {
        frameNow = 0;
    } else if (frameNow >= animationNumFrames) {
        frameNow = animationNumFrames - 1;
    }

    [self animationShowFrame: frameNow];
//  animationStep = frameNow + 1;

    if (animationStep >= animationNumFrames) {
        [self stopAnimating];

        // Continue to loop animation until loop counter reaches 0

        if (animationRepeatCount > 0) {
            self.animationRepeatCount = animationRepeatCount - 1;
            [self startAnimating];
        }
    }
}

- (void) stopAnimating
{
    if (![self isAnimating])
        return;

    [animationTimer invalidate];
    self.animationTimer = nil;

    animationStep = animationNumFrames - 1;
    [self animationShowFrame: animationStep];

    if (avAudioPlayer != nil) {
        [avAudioPlayer stop];
        avAudioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0;
        self->lastReportedTime = 0.0;
    }

    // Send notification to object(s) that regestered interest in a stop action

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:ImageAnimatorDidStopNotification
     object:self];  
}
```

**Edit2:** So I commented out an NSAssert in DeAlloc, commenting that out shed a bit more light. Now getting to `self.animationTimer = nil;` and saying `*** -ImageAnimator setAnimationTimer:]: Message sent to deallocated instance.`

DeAlloc is being called right when I invalidate the timer... so I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: If you're getting SIGABRT, that usually means you're hitting an assertion. Look in your logs to see what the assertion is.

Comment: Hmmm there was an NSAssert in DeAlloc... commenting that out shed a bit more light... It's now getting to 'self.animationTimer = nil;' and saying *** -ImageAnimator setAnimationTimer:]: Message sent to deallocated instance. DeAlloc is being called right after I invalidate the timer... so I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: You are probably calling the timer `-(void) animationTimerCallback: (NSTimer *)timer` after you release it...

Comment: I get that, I don't understand how to keep that from happening. I call the stopAnimation command and it gets into that function and the first thing it does is hits invalidate then jumps over to DeAlloc could my app be calling animationTimerCallback when I'm calling stopAnimation?

Comment: While you should always access your ivars through access, dealloc is the big exception. Release your ivars directly in dealloc. That said, this error suggests that you're either calling [super dealloc] at the beginning of your dealloc (it must be called at the end), or `self` has been over-released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution which is working but not optimal.

I just added another function to set the frame it's on to the last frame and it ends the sequence as I need.

But it doesn't solve the question of why it's doing it's crashing if I try to stop the sequence mid run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wrote this code so I can assure you that it should be working just fine :) You need to invoke stopAnimating before you are done with the view, the only way you would have got the assert in dealloc is if the view was deallocated while it was still animating. That should not happen, which is exactly why there way an assert there. There is also a big comment explaining the assert, what is unclear about that?

```
- (void)dealloc {
  // This object can't be deallocated while animating, this could
  // only happen if user code incorrectly dropped the last ref.

  NSAssert([self isAnimating] == FALSE, @"dealloc while still animating");

  self.animationURLs = nil;
  self.imageView = nil;
  self.animationData = nil;
  self.animationTimer = nil;

  [super dealloc];
}
```

Just call:

```
[view stopAnimating];
```

Before you remove the view from its superview and everything will be just fine.